# Creating a dynamic ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I was thinking of creating a CMS for my own website, I thought it would be eaiser to create pages and update the meta tags and content on the fly. When I thought about it more, I realised I could update the content in say...

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  ViewBag = "My Content";
  return View(); 
}
```

But I never thought about creating new pages, referencing them in my database, and using the correct Controllers.

Is there a way to dynamically create Controllers / ActionResults and corresponding Views in MVC?

Kind regards

James

Comment: Well.. yes, but that is so much more complicated than just having a nice routing / url scheme and having a single controller load what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could take the approach that many CMS systems use which is to assign each page an ID in your database along with the page content and then have a single controller that looks up and displays the page

I.e.:

```
public ActionResult Index(string pageID)
{
    //Query the database for content for page with ID of pageID
    ViewBag.Content = //Result from DB;
    return View(); 
}
```

and then in your page just display the content. If the content contains HTML tags use:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Content)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need different views for the pages, going through the same action, you can do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(string pageID)
{
    //Query the database for content for page with ID of pageID
    ViewBag.Content = //Result from DB;
    return View("/path/to/other/view"); 
}
```

However, this is considered a bad practice, use at own discretion.
http://forums.asp.net/t/1596709.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want friendly URLs, I would do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Page(string url)
{
    return Content("content for url");
}
```

and then you would have a route that looks like:

```
routes.MapRouteLowercase(
    "Page",
    "{*url}",
    new {controller = "CmsPage", action = "Page", url = UrlParameter.Optional});
```